# How to select rows with specific condition within specific ranage in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql that has two columns. Id and number. First time list all rows from 4 to 13 by

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13`

now I have a list of all rows from 4 to 13. (green rows)

I want to search in this list and find the first row where number is <= 10 and the last row where the number is <= 1000 and all rows inbetween. I.e. I need the orange rows shown in the image below:

[image]

So, I need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13
  AND number
  START
  FROM <= 10
  AND END WITH <= 1000
```

But obviously the above isn't correct. How can I obtain the orange rows?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, `SELECT *
FROM TABLE WHERE (id BETWEEN 4 AND 13) AND (number BETWEEN 10 AND 1000)`?

Comment: Why is id 8, number 5464 selected then?

Comment: Yes number BETWEEN 10 AND 1000 BUT I need all rows between 10 and 1000 too. I don't want to loose them.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to imply here

Comment: if between 10 and 1000 why 8,0,5 and 5464 selected?

Comment: So from ID 4 to 13 you want everything from the first time you reach an entry with `number <= 10` and from that entry until `number >=1000` is that right?

Comment: I just want all orange rows where number start from 10 and finish with 1000

Comment: @Andresch Serj: Exactly

Comment: Please don't give negative when you don't understand my question. This is different from what you think. I think that is a good question. Andresch Serj know what I asked.

Comment: ohhh i see.. you want to search from 4 to 13 row where first number from top is <=10 and search from row 13 to 4 where last number <=1000

Comment: @UserMat Try my Answer as well. And weather or not this is a good question - it was fun to solve :D ... thou, remember to accept an answer and upvote those you did enjoy. Have a nice DOS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT  T.ID, T.Number
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MIN(CASE WHEN Number < 10 THEN ID END) AS FirstID,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN Number < 1000 THEN ID END) AS LastID
            FROM    T
            WHERE   ID BETWEEN 4 AND 13 
        ) AS ID
            ON ID.FirstID <= T.ID
            AND ID.LastID >= T.ID
```

The key is the subquery -

```
SELECT  MIN(CASE WHEN Number < 10 THEN ID END) AS FirstID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Number < 1000 THEN ID END) AS LastID
FROM    T
WHERE   ID BETWEEN 4 AND 13
```

Which gets the first ID less than 10 in the given range, and the last ID less than 1000 in the given range. These ID's are then used to filter the results.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50988/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT MyTable.* FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM T WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13) as MyTable
JOIN (
  SELECT ID, NUMBER 
  FROM T 
  WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13 
  AND NUMBER <= 10 LIMIT 1
  ) as StartRow
JOIN (
  SELECT ID, NUMBER 
  FROM T       
  WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13 
  AND NUMBER <= 1000 
  ORDER BY ID DESC 
  LIMIT 1
  ) as EndingRow
WHERE MyTable.ID BETWEEN StartRow.ID and EndingRow.ID
```

See the [sqlFiddle Demo working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50988/13)

You select over your subquery, the green rows that represent the ids 4 to 13.
Then in the main select, use `joins` to get your borders of your orange rows.

Let's walk thru this step by step.
First, you select your rows between the id 4 and 13 (*green rows*) and name the result MyTable.

```
SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT * FROM T WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13) as MyTable
```

Now you need to know the first element in this subset that is below or equal to 10 (`<=10`).
In my Approach i `join` the result again and add this clause to it while also shrinki8ng the resultset to 1 using `Limit`.

```
JOIN (
      SELECT ID, NUMBER 
      FROM T 
      WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13 
      AND NUMBER <= 10 LIMIT 1
      ) as StartRow
```

So now for every row in your `4 to 13` Result, you have the field StartRow.ID as well.
The same works for the end of your orange list. The last one of the `4 to 13` that is <=1000.

```
JOIN (
      SELECT ID, NUMBER 
      FROM T       
      WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13 
      AND NUMBER <= 1000 
      ORDER BY ID DESC 
      LIMIT 1
      ) as EndingRow
```

By adding `DESC` to the `ORDER` Statement, i get the last element that matches my query and not the first.

Now we just have to put that into the capsulating Query's Where clause:

```
  WHERE MyTable.ID BETWEEN StartRow.ID and EndingRow.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$arr = array();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13 ") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $arr[$row['id']] = $row['number']; // put id and number in array
}

$first_key = 0; 
$last_key = 0; 


// getting first key    
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    if($val <= 10)
    {
        $first_key = $key; 
        break;
    }
}

// getting last key 
$arr_reverse = array_reverse($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    if($val <= 1000)
    {
        $last_key = $key; 
        break;
    }
}

// getting values form first key to last key
$arr_output = array();

foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    if($key>=$first_key && $key<=$last_key)
    {
        $arr_output[$key] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

NOTE : mysql_* is Deprecated. i used here for example. use mysqli or pdo

Comment: In general, fetching a greater value-set and then process it client-side (in this context in PHP) is not a good choice, since the DBMS is certainly better in handling the result set. Moreover, this case is not that hard to solve in plain SQL.

Comment: this is logic based. i think not solved by a single sql statement as OP's requirement. if you have i will really appreciated.

Comment: There was effort put into your answer (*which is always cool!*) but i also think the various SQL/DBMS Solutions are superior.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ID BETWEEN
(SELECT MIN(id)FROM
(
 SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13
) s 
WHERE number <= 10)
AND
(SELECT MAX(id)FROM
(
 SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13
) s 
WHERE number <= 1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about...

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 13 AND number BETWEEN 10 AND 1000`

?

Comment: I want all orange rows. By your method it just select row 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12. But I want row number 8 too.

Comment: @UserMat So `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (id BETWEEN 4 AND 13) OR (number BETWEEN 10 AND 1000)` ?

Comment: I cannot grasp what are you trying to do. Didn't you want to search by number INSIDE rows that already matched ID? If so, you must use AND. If you use OR, you will get all rows whose number is between 10 and 1000 no matter what ID they have. Please, try first to clarify your question before marking answers down.

Comment: (1) I didn't downvote.(2) I'm not the OP.(3) It was directed to the OP and not you

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Anyway, I'm not sure about what do you want to get. You have two criteria: ID range and number range. Now, What do you want to get? If you want only rows that match BOTH criteria, use AND. If you want rows that match ANY criteria (or both), use OR.

Comment: It's not about what **I** want. It's about what OP wants. And the comment I made was for the OP to give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (id BETWEEN 4 AND 13)) WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN 10 AND 1000
```

Comment: That's just a needlessly complex query -1.